# How to configure Azurite Docker Container to Use public URLs for the containing objects?

Tags: azurite

I'm currently running the Azurite Docker container on my Virtual Machine via docker-compose, and I'm encountering an issue with public URLs for the uploaded files. The public URLs generated by Azurite look like `http://azurite:10000/...`, which prevents me from accessing these objects externally. Is there a configuration option that allows me to make public URLs start from the VM's IP address?

Here's my `docker-compose` configuration for reference:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
    azurite:
        container_name: azurite
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
        command: "azurite-blob --blobHost 0.0.0.0"
        ports:
            - "10000:10000"

     web-api:
         image: ...
         ports:
             - "8080:80"
         environment:
             - ConnectionStrings__AzuriteConnectionString=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://azurite:10000/devstoreaccount1;
         depends_on:
             - azurite
```

Comment: Few questions....why would you rather use ip than name. The containers up address could change. Using the service name makes this resilient. When you say ip x.x.x.x is this ip of the machine or the ip of the container inside the docker network ?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle it's IP of the machine. Actually, I need it for another task: I have a storage account container (azurite) and api-service. When I get the public URL of the file uploaded to storage container, it returns local URL, so I can't access it from another host

Comment: This comment is the most important part of your question.  I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem: probably that storage container has some cfg option for this use case.  The ["host" network mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/) should solve your problem but I don't recommend this solution because, again, it would be the solution for the wrong problem.

Answer (score -1):

It is a best practice to use swarm or kubernetes in this scenario. docker-compose is suitable for running containers in your local machine. Since you're using a remote VM, I think that no doubts you're having such problem.